# Check for function data in querying posts for a shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display posts in a query loop called by a shortcode.
I want to show all posts paginated.

First I need to display posts with the metadata `mnp_is_new_post()` returning `true`.

Second to show the  posts with the metadata `mnp_is_new_post()` returning `false`.

Lastly pagination

Comment: Does the function refer to a database column? Perhaps, you could use `orderby` https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109853

Comment: I dont think so, it is not actually a meta field but a function that returns true if the post does not have a cookie. -> da.wordpress.org/plugins/mark-new-posts –

Answer (score 1):

@tiny. Please update your $query_args below.

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page'    =>  $atts["per_page"], 
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'          => 'mnp_is_new_post',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
);
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding~ :)

Comment: It seems not to work as mnp_is_new_post() is not actually a meta field but a function that returns true if the post does not have a cookie. -> https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/mark-new-posts/